# Use Json to get Twitter feed then convert output to PHP variable using PHP? - tweet-2-json Script

Tags: javascript, php, json, twitter

I want to get just the text of that last twitter post of a user. I found code that abstracts a users feed to the json format but How do I get the json vars to php vars? And in 'partucalar' the 'TEXT' var as seen below.

Here is the Script I am using to convert the twitter feed to json: [LINK TO CODE](https://github.com/cosmocatalano/tweet-2-json/blob/master/tweet2json.php)
HOWEVER, This is irrelevant to this question. I just need the output vars to become php vars. I was already down voted so I am giving more details.

Here is the json output:

```
{
    "tweets": [
        {
            "url": "http://twitter.com/cosmocatalano/status/343768531101417474",
            "text": "This is a test tweet. @ Sufferloft http://instagram.com/p/aWFnSJInU-/ ",
            "html": "This is a test tweet. @ Sufferloft <a href=\"http://t.co/XRaizXhwYz\" rel=\"nofollow\" dir=\"ltr\" data-expanded-url=\"http://instagram.com/p/aWFnSJInU-/\" class=\"twitter-timeline-link\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"http://instagram.com/p/aWFnSJInU-/\" ><span class=\"invisible\">http://</span><span class=\"js-display-url\">instagram.com/p/aWFnSJInU-/</span><span class=\"invisible\"></span><span class=\"tco-ellipsis\"><span class=\"invisible\">&nbsp;</span></span></a>",
            "date": "1370795779",
            "user": "/cosmocatalano",
            "id": "14503633",
            "img": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2225916199/image_normal.jpg",
            "name": "Cosmo Catalano",
            "rt": false,
            "card": {
                "href": "http://instagram.com/p/aWFnSJInU-/",
                "data-url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/9d54f23ed12211e29fe522000a1f97ce_5.jpg",
                "data-resolved-url-large": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/9d54f23ed12211e29fe522000a1f97ce_7.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the TWEET text:
// Example
variable

```
$Tweet = jsondecode(text);
echo $Tweet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JSON string is stored in `$jsonString`.

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonString);
echo $obj->tweets[0]->text; // get the first tweet
```

Or loop over them if there's more than one tweet:

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach($obj->tweets as $tweet)
{
    echo $tweet->text;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That did it.